# What effect does rc_sys="docker" have?

Tags: gentoo, docker, init, openrc

The official [Gentoo Dockerfile](https://github.com/gentoo/gentoo-docker-images/blob/master/amd64-nomultilib/Dockerfile) contains this line:

```
RUN sed -e 's/#rc_sys=""/rc_sys="docker"/g' -i /etc/rc.conf
```

As of the present time, Gentoo's [default init is OpenRC](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Comparison_of_init_systems).

If I run the docker image with `CMD /sbin/init`, issuing OpenRC-type commands gives the response

```
You are attempting to run an openrc service on a system which openrc did not boot.
```

...and, indeed, `strings /sbin/init | grep -q "sysvinit"` gives `SYSVINIT`

However, also from the above link, OpenRC is based on sysvinit, so that could be correct.

If I run the docker image with `CMD /sbin/openrc`, the image will not start, claiming dependency errors.

If I want to run multiple processes under OpenRC, should I change /etc/rc.conf back to "" (Nothing special)?

Is there something special about the "docker" RC system?  Does it, perhaps, presume no init system and instead expect only one running process?

***What does a "docker" RC in /etc/rc.conf mean in terms of what init system is used?***

Comment: Here's a link to the actual commit of the config change:  https://gitweb.gentoo.org/proj/openrc.git/commit/?id=9fedb3b40b5983372b2c2de29dfe321c6dfaadf4&context=9  It's described as "Same as -jail, but for docker systems."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at many of the `boot` runlevel init scripts, such as `/etc/init.d/hostname`, you will see a block as follows:

```
depend() {
    keyword -docker -lxc -prefix -systemd-nspawn
}
```

This states that the init script should NOT be used automatically on any of those system types (you can see the manpage `openrc-run(8)` for the full explanation of `keyword`).

The scripts may still be started manually, but will not be considered during automatic init dependency building. I don't recall offhand the behavior if the script is explicitly added to a runlevel.